# Replacing values of a cell in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cells

Assume M is a 5x1 cell and it looks like:

```
3x3 double
3x3 double
3x3 double
3x3 double
3x3 double
```

To exemplify, first cell is:

```
3  NaN  1
0   1  NaN
4   8   9
```

I want to replace NaN values with zero for each cell. However, since cellfun does not support explicit assignment (=), I cannot use it properly as follows:

```
D = cellfun(@(x) x(isnan(x)) = 0, D, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `cellfun` then.  Use an actual `for` loop:

```
for ii = 1 : numel(D)
    D{ii}(isnan(D{ii})) = 0;
end
```

`cellfun` is essentially a `for` loop under the hood.  However, if you're really set on using `cellfun`, since anonymous functions don't support assignment, one thing you *could* do is write a supplementary function that performs what you're trying to do in your code, then provide a handle to this function when you use `cellfun`.

Make a function called `replace_nan` that contains the following:

```
function x = replace_nan(x)
    x(isnan(x)) = 0;
end
```

Now call `cellfun`:

```
D = cellfun(@replace_nan, D, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Yes, I was curious about how it can be done by using cellfun. I know it is already  possible with for loop. However, I did not know that I am able to use a supplementary function in cellfun. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: No problem at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
N = cell2mat(M);
N(isnan(N)) = 0;
M = mat2cell(N,[3,3,3,3,3],3);
```

The last line should be adjusted in case your arrays are a different size.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this code size agnostic? It'd be nice to not have to change the last line of code to suit the dimensions of the input, but actually using the dimensions itself to do that automatically.

Comment: @rayryeng Assuming all matrices in the cell array have the same number of columns, the last line in my solution can be replaced with `M = mat2cell(N,cellfun(@(x)size(x,1),M),size(M{1},2));`  This solution only works for column cell arrays whose contents are numeric matrices all with the same number of columns.